# How to simplify JSON result for SPARQL queries

Tags: python, sparql, wikidata, sparqlwrapper

I'm querying Wikidata using [SPARQLWrapper](https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper).

The JSON result I'm receiving has this structure:

> "title":{"xml:lang":"en","type":"literal","value":"natural language
>   processing"}

I would like to get a simple JSON result with only the 'value' attribute:

> "title":"natural language processing"

How can I do that? is there a way to format my query or to change the python code to get a simple result?

EDIT:
Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription {
    ?item wdt:P31* wd:Q413
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Thanks

Comment: _is there a way to format my query_ That information is likely in the documentation for  SPARQLWrapper. _or to change the python code to get a simple result?_ We can't see your code, so that might be difficult.

Comment: @AMC added the query, thanks

Comment: there is no way for this format, it's basically defined in the standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/ - but honestly, I don't understand why you need this. I mean, you're using SPARQLWrapper, so why not using their API method to process the result? So why not using the RDFLib methods as intended?

Comment: And if you really need it, just modify the JSON via Python. Or use some other return type and don't use SPARQLWrapper at all: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#SPARQL_endpoint

Comment: Apache Jena has a non-standard extension: